# disable button click effect in bootstrap

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootstrap 4 and I have a small issue with buttons

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-btn">Rechercher</button>
```

This is how the button shows up

[image]

When I click on it, it stays the same but just after the mouse leaves it it becomes like this
[image]

It only shows when I click again with the mouse or the mouse is inside it

I think this has an issue with active selector but I can't find what is causing this problem

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate the issue. I think you're talking about focus? 
    https://codepen.io/amitozdeol/pen/dKOLKB

```
.btn-success:focus, .btn-success.focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Browser: Chrome MacOS
Can you share the jsfiddle or codepen with us?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, i think it has something to do with active class

Comment: Try adding `.btn.active{
  background-color: #1e7e34 !important;
} `

Answer (score -1):

The click effect was coming from the btn class so I removed it from the button

I changed this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-btn">Rechercher</button>
```

To this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-success form-btn">Rechercher</button>
```